# Force Y label on scale_y_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Problem: When using scale_y_continuous() the Y axis label is removed.

Example:

```
dat <- data.frame(variable = c("A","B","C"),
value = c(0.5,0.25,0.25)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value)) +
geom_bar() +
scale_y_continuous("", formatter="percent") + 
labs(y="Proportion",x="Type")
```

Is there a way to force the label to show when using scale_y_continuous()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It seems to me that the label disappears because you told it to be a blank string, and the later call to `labs(y=...)` doesn't override this.  Both of the following alternative formulations work:

**Option 1** is to not use `scale_y_continuous(formatter=...)`, i.e. don't provide any label text.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_y_continuous(formatter="percent") + 
    labs(y="Proportion", x="Type")
```

**Option 2** is to specify the label text in the the call to scale directly, i.e. `scale_y_continuous("Proportion", ...)`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_y_continuous("Proportion", formatter="percent") + 
    labs(x="Type")
```

[image]

Comment: /slaps forehead. I was telling it to do nothing with ""